# Relation Between the Different Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, nomenclature

From my understanding, there are 4 "types" in Haskell:

- Algebraic data type with `data`
- <del>Data type constructors (what's after the `=` in the `data` types; not types technically, I don't think)</del>
- Type alias with `type`
- Typeclasses with `class`
- Type instances with `instance`

The questions are:

1. If there are more kinds of types in Haskell. If so, what there relations are.
2. What the difference is between a `data` type and a `class` typeclass. They seem similar, though obviously they have some different features. Same with (3).
3. What the difference is between a `data` type and a `instance` typeclass instance.

I am new to Haskell.

Comment: A data type constructor is *not* a type. It is a "value", so one meta level lower than types.

Comment: The same with `class` and `instance`. I think it is a bit unfortunate that the nomenclature of Haskell is quite similar to that of most imperative programming languages, but actually has some very different meanings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`data` and `newtype` introduce new types (or type constructors actually - `Maybe` isn't a type, but `Maybe a` is a type for any `a` that is a type).

A `data` declaration introduces both a new type (what's left of the `=`) and a way to represent data of that type (what's right of the `=`).

So for example, if you have a data declaration like this:

```
data SomeType = SomeConstructor
```

Then you have introduced a new type called `SomeType`, and a way to construct values of `SomeType`, namely the constructor `SomeConstructor` (which incidentally doesn't have any parameters, so is the the only value inhabiting this type).

A typeclass doesn't do *either* of these things (and neither does an `instance`). A typeclass introduces a *constraint* and a bunch of polymorphic functions that should be available if that constraint is met. An `instance` is basically saying "this type meets this constraint" by providing an implementation for these functions. So a `class` isn't really introducing new types, it's just a way to provide ad-hoc polymorphism for existing types.

For instance, the `Show` typeclass is roughly this:

```
class Show a where -- a is an instance of Show if
   show :: a -> String -- it has a function called show with this signature
```

(Note that the actual `Show` class in `Prelude` doesn't *quite* look like this)

`show` now has the type `Show a => a -> String`, which you can read as

> for all a, if they meet the constraint `Show` (or alternatively, if they are an instance of `Show`) this is a function that takes an `a` and returns a string

An instance for this would look like this

```
instance Show SomeType where
  show SomeConstructor = "SomeConstructor"
```

Which means

> `SomeType` satisfies the constraint `Show`, and I'll show you how by providing an implementation of `show`

That's roughly the gist of it. There are language extensions that allow somewhat more involved things to happen with type classes and instances, but you don't need to worry about that for now.

Comment: In GHC Haskell with `ConstraintKinds`, typeclasses do introduce new types in a way, not for ordinary types (of kind `*`) but for constraints; `class Num a where { … }; class Functor f where { … }` creates the type constructors `Num :: * -> Constraint` and `Functor :: (* -> *) -> Constraint`. Constraints are still types, they’re just not inhabited by values.

Answer (score 3):

You may have heard of *kinds*, which are the "types of types" in Haskell. A type is something with kind `*`, which represents things that can have values:

```
> :kind Int
Int :: *
> :kind Char
Char :: *
```

Type constructors are things with kind `* -> *`; a type constructor takes a type (something of kind `*`) and returns another type.

```
> :kind Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
> :kind []
[] :: * -> *
```

Applying a type constructor gives you a new thing of kind `*`:

```
> :kind Maybe Int
Maybe Int :: *
> :kind [] Float
[] Float :: *
```

(The parser allow `[Foo]` as a special case for `[] Foo`.)

There are other things that are kinds as well. One of them is `Constraint`, and you create a `Constraint` with a constraint constructor (otherwise known as a type class). Give a constraint constructor a type, and you get back a constraint.

```
> :kind Show
Show :: * -> Constraint
> :kind Show Int
Show Int :: Constraint
> :kind Show (Int -> Char)
Show (Int -> Char) :: Constraint
```

(Note that the latter is properly kinded even though no instance for `Int -> Char` is defined.)

---

In this light, `=>` looks something like an operator, rather than just special syntax. Its arguments are a "list" of constraints (albeit using universally quantified type variables instead of concrete types) and a type, and its return value is a "constrained" type (let's pretend there is a kind `ConstrainedType` in addition to `*`, `* -> *`, and `Constraint`).

```
:t show
show :: Show a => a -> String

-- Taking extreme liberties with syntax
-- :k (=>)
-- (=>) :: [Constraint] -> * -> ConstrainedType
-- A section?
-- :k (Show a =>)
-- (Show a =>) :: * -> ConstrainedType
-- :k (Showa => * -> String)
-- Show a => a -> String :: ConstrainedType
```